# Clear TextView focus when "down" (hide keyboard) button is pressed

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

How can I change what code is executed when the user hides the keyboard by pressing the "down" button? (when the back button transforms into a downwards arrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    //Clear textview focus here
    return true;  
  }
  return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```